# jquery ajax method in asp net without using webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Aspx Page

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#Content").text(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frm" method="post">
    <div id="Content">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
public static string GetData()
{
    return "This string is from Code behind";
}
```

I want to get this function using ajax without using "WEBMETHOD". i.e. `GetData()` method, I want to show in my .aspx page without using web service.

Comment: You need webmethod attribute.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure i get your question but maybe what you are looking for is simply the code you need in the `onload` event of the page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Response.Write("put a valid json string here");
    }
```